# Cantonese Joke About Dealing With Mandarin Elitists?

Tags: cantonese, humor

Came across this on [Reddit/Jokes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/lnljut/an_englishman_is_hiking_in_scotland_and_he_pauses/) today

> An Englishman is hiking in Scotland and he pauses to drink from a stream. A passing shepherd calls out "Dinnae drink frae that, it's all fulla coo piss an shite!"
>
> The Englishman says to him in a cut-glass accent "I'm terribly sorry, my good fellow, would you very much mind repeating that in the Queen's English?" And the shepherd says "I'm terribly sorry sir, I was only asking if you would like to borrow this tin cup and get a proper drink?"

[One of the comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/lnljut/an_englishman_is_hiking_in_scotland_and_he_pauses/go2tmbj?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) says:

> In Hong Kong, you get the same joke but with mandarin elitists and Cantonese speakers.

Apparently a lot of similar language jokes are about poison and not just contaminated water.

Any idea what the joke is in Cantonese?

Comment: What does mean "Dinnae drink frae that"? ('Don't drink that'?)

Comment: @starckman Probably: Don't drink from that

Comment: Until someone comes up with the joke, here's one to warm things up.                                                                    Q: 一块三分熟的牛排在街上走着，突然他在前方看到一块五分熟的牛排，可却没有理会他 …他们为什么没打招呼?
                                                                                                                              A: …因为他们不熟！

Comment: There is a Cantonese VS. English Elitist one: 香蕉 didn't have an English name until one day an English man saw a Cantonese guy eating one. This English man said to his friend: "Do the Cantonese know how stupid they look when they eat this yellow fruit like a monkey?" Unexpectedly, that  Cantonese did know English and got very angry. He beat that English man with the 香蕉 over his head and yelled:" 笨吖嗱?! 笨吖嗱?!" (Stupid, huh?! Stupid, huh?!). And That's how 香蕉 got named Banana in English. -- (笨吖嗱 is pronounced  'ban6 a1 na2' )

Comment: @starckman, even less obvious is "coo", which means "cow".

Answer (score 1):

In Cantonese-speaking world, the joke in Cantonese could be:

`近日最流行的粤语：`

`第一句：叮咚鸡 - Mandarin （听通知 original Cantonese meaning）`

`第二句：大狗叫 - Mandarin （戴口罩 original Cantonese meaning）`

```
https://twitter.com/m_wo8y/status/1512995205431324675  (the twitter version)


https://www.douyin.com/video/7077715908835167500  (the video version)
```

Comment: it doesn't sound like an answer to the question.